# UDP comunication with Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, udp

I would like to exchange data between pc and a raspberry using udp protocol in a tkinter gui. The pc is the UDP client, sending commands to raspberry, while the raspberry is the UDP server that makes things (eg. read sensors values, activate pump...) according to the command received from the client.

The problem is that when I try to send commands from pc to Rpi through a Tkinter gui (button pressing), the tkinter gui crashes.

Below the script for the Client (pc) with tkinter gui and UDP socket.

```
import socket, time
import pickle
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import IdentityTransform
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import csv
import os
import seaborn as sns
from threading import Thread


serverAddress = ('172.16.14.75', 2222)  #raspberry address
LEN_UDP_BUFFER = 1024

def sock_rdt(s, timeout=1800.0): #1800.0
    s.settimeout(timeout)
    try:
        return s.recvfrom(LEN_UDP_BUFFER)
    except:
        return "".encode('utf-8'), ("", 0)


UDPClient = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

def Heating_cmd():
    cmd = 'Heating'
    cmd = cmd.encode('utf-8')
    UDPClient.sendto(cmd, serverAddress)
    data, address = sock_rdt(UDPClient)
    if data:
        print(pickle.loads(data))
    else:
        print("Timeout ricezione!")


def Emptying_cmd():
    cmd = 'Emptying'
    cmd = cmd.encode('utf-8')
    UDPClient.sendto(cmd, serverAddress)
    data, address = sock_rdt(UDPClient)
    if not data:
        print("Timeout ricezione!")
    #if data:
        #print(pickle.loads(data))
    #else:
    #   print("Timeout ricezione!")

def Cleaning_cmd():
    cmd = 'Cleaning'
    cmd = cmd.encode('utf-8')
    UDPClient.sendto(cmd, serverAddress)
    data, address = sock_rdt(UDPClient)
    if data:
        print(pickle.loads(data))
    else:
        print("Timeout ricezione!")


def Close():
    UDPClient.sendto("stop server".encode('utf-8'), serverAddress)
    UDPClient.close()
    root.destroy()


def Analysis_cmd():
    cmd = 'Analysis'
    cmd = cmd.encode('utf-8')
    UDPClient.sendto(cmd, serverAddress)
    data, address = sock_rdt(UDPClient)
    if data:
        output = pickle.loads(data)
        with open(datapath + '/' + 'Misure.csv', "a") as f:  
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(output[:-1])
            f.close()
        message1 = f"ISO Code: {output[5]}"
        message2 = f"RH index ([0 - 100 %]): {output[2]}"
        message3 = f"Contamination index ([0 - 13]): {output[1]}"
        message4 = f"Viscosity index: {output[4]}"
        message5 = f"Oil Temperature (°C): {output[3]}"

        # Plot histogram area and ISO code
        intervals = list(range(0,110,10))
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
        sns.histplot(data=output[-1], bins=intervals, stat='count')
        ax.set_xticks(ticks=intervals,fontsize=8)
        ax.set_xlabel('Particle size (μm)')
        ax.set_ylabel('Counts')
        ax.text(700, 500, message1, color="firebrick", fontsize=15,transform=IdentityTransform())
        ax.text(700, 450, message2, color="dimgray", fontsize=15,transform=IdentityTransform())
        ax.text(700, 400, message3, color="dimgray", fontsize=15,transform=IdentityTransform())
        ax.text(700, 350, message4, color="dimgray", fontsize=15,transform=IdentityTransform())
        ax.text(700, 300, message5, color="dimgray", fontsize=15,transform=IdentityTransform())
        plt.show()


    else:
        print("Timeout ricezione!")


def get_value():
    global filename, filepath
    filename = file_entry.get()
    filepath = path_entry.get()
    fields = ['timestamp','Contamination_Index','RH_Index','Oil_Temperature','Viscosity_Index','ISO','>4 micro','>6 micro','>14 micro']
    
    if not file_entry.get() and not path_entry.get():
        messagebox.showerror(title="Error", message='Insert path and directory')
    elif not os.path.isdir(filepath):
        messagebox.showerror(title="Error", message='Invalid directory')
    elif not file_entry.get():
        messagebox.showerror(title="Error", message='Invalid filename')
    else:
        if not(os.path.exists(filepath + '/' + filename + '.csv')):
            with open(filepath + '/' + filename + '.csv', "w+") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(fields)

# Graphical User Interface
root = Tk()
root.title('Oil Analyzer')
root.geometry('460x460')
root.resizable(False,False)
root.config(bg = 'grey85')

s = ttk.Style()
colorFrame = 'DarkSeaGreen1'
colorButtonbase = 'SteelBlue1'
colorButtonactive = 'SteelBlue3'
s.configure('new.TFrame', background=colorFrame)

frame1 = ttk.Frame(root,borderwidth=5, relief="ridge",  style='new.TFrame')
frame2 = ttk.Frame(root,borderwidth=5, relief="ridge",  style='new.TFrame')


login_label = Label(frame1, text = "Information for data saving", bg=colorFrame, fg='OrangeRed3', font =("Calibri",14))
path_label = Label(frame1, text = "Directory path", bg=colorFrame, font =("Calibri",12), justify="right")
path_entry = Entry(frame1, width=30)
file_entry = Entry(frame1, width=30)
file_label = Label(frame1, text = "Filename",bg=colorFrame, font =("Calibri",12), justify="right")
save_button = Button(frame1, text = "Save", bg = 'indian red', activebackground = 'IndianRed4', font =("Calibri",12), command = get_value)
commands_label = Label(frame2, text = "Oil Analyzer Section", bg=colorFrame, fg='OrangeRed3', font =("Calibri",14))
button1 = Button(frame2, text='Heating', command = Heating_cmd, bg = colorButtonbase, activebackground = colorButtonactive, font =("Calibri",12))
button2 = Button(frame2,text='Analysis', command = Analysis_cmd, bg = colorButtonbase, activebackground = colorButtonactive, font =("Calibri",12))
button3 = Button(frame2, text='Emptying', command = Emptying_cmd, bg = colorButtonbase, activebackground = colorButtonactive, font =("Calibri",12))
button4 = Button(frame2,text='Cleaning', command = Cleaning_cmd, bg = colorButtonbase, activebackground = colorButtonactive, font =("Calibri",12))
exit_button = Button(frame2, text='Exit', command = Close, bg = 'indian red', activebackground = 'IndianRed4', font =("Calibri",12))

frame1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="nsew")
login_label.grid(column=0, columnspan = 2, row=0, pady=10, padx=10, sticky=W)
path_label.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=15, pady=5,sticky = E)
path_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=5, pady=5)
file_label.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=15, pady=5, sticky = E)
file_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=5, pady=5)
save_button.grid(column=4, row=2, padx=18, pady=8, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

frame2.grid(column=0, row=6, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="nsew")
commands_label.grid(column=1, row=5, columnspan = 2,pady=10, padx=10, sticky=W)
button1.grid(column=1, row=6, padx=15, pady=15, ipady=10, ipadx=30, sticky = E)
button2.grid(column=1, row=7, padx=15, pady=15, ipady=10, ipadx=30,sticky = E)
button3.grid(column=2, row=6, padx=15, pady=15, ipady=10, ipadx=30,sticky = W)
button4.grid(column=2, row=7, padx=15, pady=15, ipady=10, ipadx=30,sticky = W)
exit_button.grid(column=4, row=7, padx=18, ipadx=8, ipady=5)



root.mainloop()
```

I read something related to Thread and root.after() functions, but I am not able to resolve my problem. I have not a continuous workflow, Rpi has to do things in accordance to the button press...

Could you provide me any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `recvfrom()` is a blocking operation by default and also you have set a very long timeout (1800 seconds).

Comment: Post a [mre] and debugging details including a stack trace.